# Random grid of elements using Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, io, io-monad, do-notation

Having absolutely zero experience with Haskell, I need to come up with a code equivalent to this Python one:

```py
from random import choice, sample

def random_subset():
    return tuple(sample(('N', 'S', 'W', 'E'), choice((1, 2, 3, 4))))

def form_grid(n):
    return [[random_subset() for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

form_grid(10)
```

which produces something like this:

```
N     ESWN  SNEW  NSE   EWSN  E     ENSW  N     NSWE  WES   
NE    WNS   SWEN  EWN   ENWS  WEN   WS    W     ENSW  NW    
WENS  NWE   SNEW  ES    E     S     ES    SENW  EW    WEN   
NSE   NE    WNE   NEWS  SNE   W     SWNE  NSWE  SNEW  EN    
S     SNW   WNES  S     WESN  E     ES    N     ESN   ES    
SWEN  S     WSNE  NEWS  WESN  E     S     SE    E     N     
NEW   S     NEW   WS    W     EN    N     NWS   E     WENS  
WN    NWE   S     SEW   NESW  EWSN  WENS  ES    NWS   WN    
W     NWE   N     N     ES    E     E     WN    SWNE  NES   
WENS  NWE   NW    WESN  SW    NES   ENWS  SE    N     SWNE
```

I, for the love of god, can't wrap my head around Haskell's concept of IO (randomness in particular). The best I could come up with is this:

```hs
import Data.Random hiding (shuffle, sample)
import Data.Random.Source.Std
import Data.Random.Extras

randSubset :: IO [Char]
randSubset = do
    len <- runRVar (choice [1..4]) StdRandom :: IO Int
    subset <- runRVar (sample len ['N', 'S', 'W', 'E']) StdRandom :: IO [Char]
    return subset

formGrid :: Int -> [[IO [Char]]]
formGrid n = [[subset | _ <- [0..(n - 1)], subset <- randSubset] | _ <- [0..(n - 1)]]
```

which still didn't do it:

```
error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[IO [Char]]'
                  with actual type `IO [Char]'
    * In the expression: randSubset
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: subset <- randSubset
      In the expression:
        [subset | _ <- [0 .. (n - 1)], subset <- randSubset]
   |
12 | formGrid n = [[subset | _ <- [0..(n - 1)], subset <- randSubset] | _ <- [0..(n - 1)]]
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Quick googling didn't help much - I probably didn't use the most accurate keywords for this problem I'm facing. Making random changes and hoping for the best is getting pretty frustrating, but I really have neither time, nor energy to dive into Haskell properly (even though it's a shame), so for now, I'd love someone to just point me to what's wrong with this code.

Comment: `randSubset` creates an `IO [Char]`, so you can not iterate over that.

Comment: Have you learnt how to use monads and `do`-notation? You'll find all IO fairly difficult until you grok that. I'd recommend [the LYAH chapter on monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) if not the entirety of LYAH to understand this.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, you're right! In fact, I don't even want to iterate over that. I just want to take the whole subsets (new every time) and place them into the cells n*n times. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the error already says, your list comprehension has a generator:

```
formGrid n = [[subset | _ <- [0..(n - 1)], subset <- randSubset] | _ <- [0..(n - 1)]]
```

So that means that it expects `randSubset` to be a list of something, but it is not a list of something, it is an `IO` of a list of something. You thus can not use that.

The type of your function is also a bit problematic, you use `[[IO [Char]]]`, so a matrix of `IO [Char]`s.

You are likely looking for [**`replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM), so then your program looks like:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

formGrid :: Int -> IO [[[Char]]]
formGrid n = replicateM n (replicateM n randSubset)
```

For example:

```
Main> formGrid 3
[["WSNE","WNS","S"],["WN","SN","WEN"],["SEWN","ESN","NESW"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement Willem's answer, I'll add that your `randSubset` looks rather complex. Here's a simpler alternative

```
randSubset :: IO String
randSubset = do
  n <- sample (Uniform 1 4)        -- choose how many elements
  sample (shuffleNofM n 4 "NSWE")  -- take that many elements
```

(That's `sample` from `Data.Random`, by the way)

You should check that this is indeed the intended distribution of subsets. Note that this is not a uniform distribution: `N` is more likely than `NS` (or even both `NS` and `SN` combined). Also note that each permutation of the same subset can occur, so we are not really sampling "subsets". I don't know which distribution is used by your Python code -- it might be the same, after all.

If you work inside `IO`, I think it's simpler if you use `sample (someDistribution)` rather than working at the lower level of `RVar`s.

After this, you can use `replicateM` to generate your grid, as Willem showed.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to jump too far at once. Start small,

```
formRow :: Int -> IO [[Char]]
formRow 0 = return [] 
formRow n = do { 
     subset  <- randSubset ;     -- subset :: [Char]   <-  randSubset :: IO [Char]
     subsets <- formRow (n-1) ;  --           ~~~~~~                        ~~~~~~
     return (subset : subsets)   -- IO [[Char]]
     }
```

... just using what you already have, here. Then do the same with the rows,

```
formGrid :: Int -> IO [[[Char]]]
formGrid 0 = return [] 
formGrid n = do { 
     row  <- formRow n ;        -- row :: [[Char]]   <-  formRow n :: IO [[Char]]
     rows <- formGrid (n-1) ;   --        ~~~~~~~~                       ~~~~~~~~
     return (row : rows)        -- IO [[[Char]]]
     }
```

and you're done. Don't fear the *`do`* notation, it's your friend. It is easy to program in, as it is its whole purpose.

When you've coded your next monadic combinator, check out its type [on Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20IO%20a%20-%3E%20IO%20%5Ba%5D) and see whether it already is in the library.

Indeed, abstracting, we see we've reimplemented

```
replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]

formRow n = replicateM n randSubset 
formGrid n = replicateM n (formRow n)
           = replicateM n (replicateM n randSubset)
```

(just as Willem's answer says; but now we know *how* and *why*).